# I want to select or view a specific data in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to retrieve store_id and store_name stores from my store table that starts with uppercase T and ends with lowercase o .. what should I type?

Comment: Add what RDMS you are using.

Comment: oracle, I'm new to databases and i didnt knew it matters

Answer (score 0):

```
Select  store_id, store_name FROM [my store table]
where left(store_name,1) = 'T' COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS 
and right(store_name,1) = 'o'  COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

Should work if you type the table name as it is, no matter upper or lower case...

```
SELECT store_id, store_name FROM To
```

or even

```
 select store_id, store_name from To
```

Can you show what you are doing, or what "editor" (eg phpmyadmin, sqlserver, etc), like the tutorial says, give some examples you have tried...

For a nuke solution, just rename the table to lowercase, which is the standard!!!

Comment: I don't think the OP is talking about the 'case' of the table name, but of the data.

Answer (score 0):

```
select store_id, store_name 
  from tableName 
 where store_name like 'T%o'
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow and thanks for your contribution! Please consider adding a description to your code; stackoverflow is about understanding what the problem is, not about copy-pasting code!